# Grep or in part of a string

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Good day All,

A filename can either be

1. abc_source_201501.csv Or,
2. abc_source2_201501.csv

Is it possible to do something like `grep abc_source|source2_201501.csv` without fully listing out filename as the filenames I'm working with are much longer than examples given to get both options?

Thanks for assistance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use extended regex flag in grep.

For example:

```
grep -E abc_source.?_201501.csv
```

would source out both lines in your example. You can think of other regex patterns that would suit your data more.

Comment: I might be wrong about your actual question tho. As to whether you are looking for these two lines or looking into files named like these two lines.

Comment: It's the latter - files with names that contain source1 or source2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) to grep in several files at once.

For example, to grep for the string "hello" in all files with a filename that starts with abc_source and ends with 201501.csv, issue this command:

```
grep hello abc_source*201501.csv
```

You can also use the -r flag, to recursively grep in all files below a given folder - for example the current folder (.).

```
grep -r hello .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about patterns for file name matching in the shell, the [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) facility in Bash lets you say

```
shopt -s extglob
grep stuff abc_source@(|2)_201501.csv
```

to search through both files with a single glob expression.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possibility is to use brace expansion:

```
grep pattern abc_{source,source2}_201501.csv
```

That's exactly the same as:

```
grep pattern abc_source{,2}_201501.csv
```

You can use several brace patterns in a single word:

```
grep pattern abc_source{,2}_2015{01..04}.csv
```

expands to

```
grep pattern abc_source_201501.csv abc_source_201502.csv \
             abc_source_201503.csv abc_source_201504.csv \
             abc_source2_201501.csv abc_source2_201502.csv \
             abc_source2_201503.csv abc_source2_201504.csv
```